# Canonical Form of $x^2+x-y=p$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Can anyone please help me to put the following equation into canonical form, with the $p$ at the end being a constant:
$$x^2+x-y^2=p$$
Or even just explain what canonical form is?

Comment: That seems to be the problem: what is the canonical form? Or better: what do you call "canonical form" to in this case?

Comment: Notice that the equation in your title and the equation in the post itself are different.

Comment: Standard form is usually taken to be $\frac{X^2}{a^2}-\frac{Y^2}{b^2}=1$ for a hyperbola, $\frac{X^2}{a^2}+\frac{Y^2}{b^2}=1$for an ellipse and $Y^2=4aX$ for a parabola.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you learning conics? $x^2+x -y^2 = p \implies \left(x+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 - y^2 = p+\dfrac{1}{4}$. But if your original equation is: $x^2+x -y = p \implies y = \left(x+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 - p - \dfrac{1}{4}$